# MySQL AND statement fails

Tags: mysql, pdo, clause

I have a query that fails It seems to be the AND statement that is failing.

```
if(isset($_POST['sea']) && $_POST['sm'] !==''){
$sm = trim($_POST['sm']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `memorials` WHERE `fname` LIKE '$sm%' OR `lname` LIKE '$sm%' OR    `comments` LIKE '$sm%' AND `status` = '2' ";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute();
```

I have added\removed  `backticks`, the 'status = '2' fails.

The following statement works in phpmyadmin

```
SELECT * FROM `memorials` WHERE `fname` LIKE 'test%' AND status = '2'
```

This statement fails in phpmyadmin

```
SELECT * FROM `memorials` WHERE `fname` LIKE 'test%' OR `lname` LIKE 'test%' AND status = '2'
```

This query searchs comment AND clause works, but ignore fname and lname

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM memorials WHERE `fname`  OR  `lname`  OR `comments`  LIKE '$sm%'  AND status = '2'    ";
```

Does anyone have a suggestion where this is (I am) failing

Thank you

Gary

Answer (score 1):

You need to include parentheses around the appropriate section.  Perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `memorials` 
WHERE (`fname` LIKE 'test%' OR `lname` LIKE 'test%') AND status = '2'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, looks like your answer and Aarolama's are the same and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Gary -- np, glad we could help!

Answer (score 1):

Operator precedence matters here. You need to add some parentheses:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `memorials` 
WHERE  ( `fname` LIKE '$sm%' 
          OR `lname` LIKE '$sm%' 
          OR `comments` LIKE '$sm%' ) 
       AND `status` = '2'
```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html).

Comment: Sorry for the delay (server went down), worked like a charm... Thank you for your help.

Comment: bluefeet - I had the question half written and tried another version and thought the more information the better.